How to Properly Implement Role-Based Authorization in React Using Context API and React Query?
I am trying to work on a React application where I want to implement role-based authorization.
My goal is to fetch user roles from an API and store them in context so they can be accessed throughout the application. I am using the Context API and React Query for state management and data fetching.
I am having trouble finding information about how to do so effectively as most information about it seems to be using old formats. Or is just about Authentication rather than Authorization.
I saw some people recommeding to use JWT-decoder on React but I dont know how safe it is to decode your token In the Client Side... nor how to properly implement it.
What I was trying to do was fetch the role straight from the server and save the data in a context and then just if check all protected routes for the correct roles (or especialidades for this proyect)
This is the context I was trying to make work:
const AuthContext = createContext<string[] | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthContextProvider = ({children} :{children:ReactNode})=>{
        const {data:roles} = useQuery({
            queryFn: ()=> fetchRole(),
            queryKey: ["roles"],
        })
        const userRoles = roles || [];

        return(
            <AuthContext.Provider value={userRoles}>
                {children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
}

export const useAuthContext = ()=>{
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    return context;
} 

// The fetch function
export const fetchRole = async ():Promise<string[]>=>{
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/api/auth/check-role",{
        credentials: "include",
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error("Something went wrong...");
    }
    return response.json();
}

//The backend Route, MiddleWare and Response
authRoutes.get('/check-role',verifyToken,async ( req:Request, res:Response)=>{
    console.log(req.medicoInfo.especialidad)
    res.status(200).json({medicoRoles: req.medicoInfo.especialidad});
})


const verifyToken = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)=>{
    const token = req.cookies["auth_cookie"];
    console.log(token);
    if(!token){
        return res.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized"});
    }
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string);
        req.medicoInfo = (decoded as JwtPayload).medicoInfo;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized"});
    }
}

//MiddleWare
const verifyToken = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction)=>{
    const token = req.cookies["auth_cookie"];
    console.log(token);
    if(!token){
        return res.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized"});
    }
    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET as string);
        req.medicoInfo = (decoded as JwtPayload).medicoInfo;
        next();
    } catch (error) {
        return res.status(401).json({message: "Unauthorized"});
    }
}

The data is being fetched but How can I implement it.. How can I make it so this data protects my Routes, and help the users navigate safely through an app.
Should I change my Context? I saw somewhere that I should just both send the token and the roles when Sign In but I am beyond lost how could I use them. I just don't know whats the next step after fetching and just putting them in a context or if it even is the best option.
